# How to permanently edit (delete) the sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

'C:\\python32\\Lib\\site-packages\\django'
'C:\\Python32'
'C:\\Python32\\lib\\site-packages'
...
```

for some reason, my pythonpath got messy. I'd like to organize it. Is it correct that I don't need the first and the last one above? And how can I change it permanently? (Not like sys.path.remove or sys.path.append)

I'm using Python3.2. in windows8.

Comment: Check your PYTHONPATH environment variable. It will need to be modified from outside of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path 'C:\Python32\lib\site-packages' is added to sys.path by the built-in [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) module.

If you want to, you can start python with the -S flag to tell the site module "Don't add site-packages".

```
python -S
```

Next, 'C:\python32\Lib\site-packages\django'.
Here's a wild guess: you installed django with pip/easy_install/msi-installer and there is a file 
C:\python32\Lib\site-packages\django.pth (or something like this ending with .pth)

Quoting the docs:

> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form name.pth
>   and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its
>   contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to sys.path.

You can remove django.pth file (not recommended, see below) to remove '..../django' from sys.path

So, short answer: don't mess with sys.path, what's in sys.path is probably for a good reason.
If you don't need django, then uninstall django using whatever tool you used to install it. Same for every package you don't need.